# VSTS intermittently nuget package restore fails

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore, azure-pipelines

How do you fix intermittent package restore fails in VSTS?

During my build I have a task to restore Nuget packages.

My build configuration does have multiple configurations for the same code.

Every so often, I get build failure where packages fails to restore, yet the the other configuration does succeed. If I do kick off the build again the build will succeed.

The error is:

> ...nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1

[image]

Comment: are you using the hosted or a custom agent?

Comment: @baywet no, I am using standard nuget restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a little research to find out the issue.

Nuget had a bug related to exactly this, which has been resolved.

**Resolution**

I have changed the configuration to use v3.5 and the issue has been resolved.

Comment: any chance you have a link to the bug?

Comment: @Mutmatt nope, as this is on my private vsts subscription